# Writing a queue to a properties file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, properties, stack, queue

Is there an easy way to write a queue to a file in Java so it can be read back?

My programme currently saves arrays to a properties file in comma delimited format. This is easy, as the array can be iterated over.

My programme also features queues. Is my only option with a queue, to remove every item from the queue and re-add them whenever I want to write all the elements of the queue to file?

What is the easiest way of implementing this?

I ideally want to save the information in the same properties file my other arrays are written to.

Comment: If you're using a `Queue`, you can traverse it using enhanced `for` loop, no need to remove any item from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream os = null;

try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(YOUR_FILE_NAME);
    os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    for(YourObjectType current : YourQueue){
        os.writeXXX(current);  //Where XXX is the appropriate write method depending on your data type
        os.writeChars(",");  //Since you mentioned wanting a comma delimiter..
    }
} catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace(); 
} finally {
    if(fos != null) fos.close();
    if(os != null) os.close();
}
```

Comment: Writing characters to an ObjectOutputStream will make it very hard to read.  Did you mean `writeObject()` instead of `write()` ?  You can't define `fos` and `os` twice.

Comment: Notice in comments //Pick the appropriate write method depending on your object type.  The Queue's underlying datatype was never mentioned in the original question, so this post was more to shed light onto the availability of the ObjectOutputStream API and let the OP go from there.  Thanks for pointing out the double declaration, I forgot to delete that when I pulled it out for the finally block.

Comment: `write()` will only work if `YourObjectType` is a `Byte` or `byte[]`, any other type will need writeObject().

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to write the queue as a single collection.

```
public static void write(String filename, Collection queue) throws IOException {
    try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectObjectStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
        oos.writeObject(queue);
    }
}
```

to read this

```
public static void read(String filename, Collection toAddTo) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))) {
        toAddTo.addAll((Collection) ois.readObject());
    }
}
```